# updating a single column in an MSSQL table based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to update a table:

```
UPDATE Table_name
SET start_date = '12/12/2015' where employee_number = 111111
```

but I need to modify hundreds of start_dates based on employee_number.

```
UPDATE Table_name
SET start_date = '12/12/2015' where employee_number = 111111  
SET start_date = '01/05/2015' where employee_number = 111112 
etc....
```

Does sql have a preferred method of updating tables for simple conditions like mine?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. But you should use ANSI date format of YYYYMMDD. The string literals you have can cause issues based on language settings.

Comment: Where is the list of changes? Is it returned by a view or stored in a table somewhere, or is it outside of the database?

Comment: the changes are outside the data base. They are in a spreadsheet:
Start_Date Employee_Number
11/12/2015 111111
01/05/2015 112121
02/12/2017 987988
06/23/2016 889789
....
....
01/12/2018 767676

Comment: If you don't want write every single update, first save the spreadsheet to the db as a table and then use my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess you have those dates in a separated table (or file). If you don't, then just create it.

Then just join both table

```
 UPDATE t
 SET t.start_date  = s.start_date 
 FROM Table_name t
 JOIN sourceTable s
  ON t.employee_number = s.employee_number
```

Comment: got it. I'll try this and let you all know, how it went.

Comment: It turns out that this was the easiest to implement, given the format the data was in.

Answer (score 0):

**new answer**

I just saw your comment that the data being from a spreadsheet. If this is a one time change, then you can load the spreadsheet into a table in SSMS and update directly from there

```
update table_name
    set table_name.start_date = excel_table.start_date
from table_name
join excel_table
    on excel_table.employee_id = table_name.employee_ie
```

---

**Original Answer**

You have a kind of ambiguous question. Does each user get it's own special date? Can you determine the users you need to update programatically?

If so, you can do something like this:

```
update table_name
set start_date = date_table.date
from table_name
join user_table
    on user_table.employee_number = table_name.employee_number 
join date_table
    on -- <date table join>
where
    -- filter users and dates here
```

Comment: ahh.. I see. I'll give it a try